# Error while getting ID of dynamically created dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div and i do append a drop-down to it. everything is fine but when i tried to get selected value of that drop-down, i get error on browser console "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined' " .

**code :**

```
var selected_index_book = document.getElementById("surah_selection");
var book_sel = selected_index_book.options[selected_index_book.selectedIndex].value;
var book_option_id=$('option:selected', $('#surah_selection')).index();
```

Comment: why don't you use easy way to get selected value ?

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to create the `#surah_selection` element?

Comment: Could you show the html?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var book_sel = $("#surah_selection option:selected").text();
var book_option_id = $("#surah_selection option:selected").attr('id');
```